# Compare multiple CSV files with Python

Tags: python, csv

I am looking to compare multiple CSV files with Python, and output a report. The number of CSV files to compare will vary, so I am having it pull a list from a directory. Each CSV has 2 columns: the first being an area code and exchange, the second being a price.
e.g.

```
1201007,0.006
1201032,0.0119
1201040,0.0106
1201200,0.0052
1201201,0.0345
```

The files will not all contain the same area codes and exchanges, so rather than a line by line comparison, I need to use the first field as the key. I then need to generate a report that says: file1 had 200 mismatches to file2, 371 lower prices than file2, and 562 higher prices than file2. I need to generate this to compare each file to each other, so this step would be repeated against file3, file4...., and then file2 against files3, etc. I would consider myself a relative noob to Python. Below is the code I have so far which just grabs the files in the directory and prints prices from all files with a total tally.

```
import csv
import os

count = 0
#dir containing CSV files
csvdir="tariff_compare"
dirList=os.listdir(csvdir)
#index all files for later use
for idx, fname in enumerate(dirList):
    print fname
    dic_read = csv.reader(open(fname))
    for row in dic_read:
        key = row[0]
        price = row[1]
        print price
        count += 1
print count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that all your data can fit in memory; if not, you will have to try loading only some sets of files at a time, or even just two files at a time.

It does the comparison and writes the output to a summary.csv file, one row per pair of files.

```
import csv
import glob
import os
import itertools

def get_data(fname):
    """
    Load a .csv file
    Returns a dict of {'exchange':float(price)}
    """
    with open(fname, 'rb') as inf:
        items = (row.split() for row in csv.reader(inf))
        return {item[0]:float(item[1]) for item in items}

def do_compare(a_name, a_data, b_name, b_data):
    """
    Compare two data files of {'key': float(value)}

    Returns a list of
      - the name of the first file
      - the name of the second file
      - the number of keys in A which are not in B
      - the number of keys in B which are not in A
      - the number of values in A less than the corresponding value in B
      - the number of values in A equal to the corresponding value in B
      - the number of values in A greater than the corresponding value in B
    """
    a_keys = set(a_data.iterkeys())
    b_keys = set(b_data.iterkeys())

    unique_to_a = len(a_keys - b_keys)
    unique_to_b = len(b_keys - a_keys)

    lt,eq,gt = 0,0,0
    pairs = ((a_data[key], b_data[key]) for key in a_keys & b_keys)
    for ai,bi in pairs:
        if ai < bi:
            lt +=1 
        elif ai == bi:
            eq += 1
        else:
            gt += 1

    return [a_name, b_name, unique_to_a, unique_to_b, lt, eq, gt]

def main():
    os.chdir('d:/tariff_compare')

    # load data from csv files
    data = {}
    for fname in glob.glob("*.csv"):
        data[fname] = get_data(fname)

    # do comparison
    files = data.keys()
    files.sort()
    with open('summary.csv', 'wb') as outf:
        outcsv = csv.writer(outf)
        outcsv.writerow(["File A", "File B", "Unique to A", "Unique to B", "A<B", "A==B", "A>B"])
        for a,b in itertools.combinations(files, 2):
            outcsv.writerow(do_compare(a, data[a], b, data[b]))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

**Edit:** user1277476 makes a good point; if you pre-sort your files by exchange (or if they are already in sorted order), you could iterate simultaneously through all your files, keeping nothing but the current line for each in memory.

This would let you do a more in-depth comparison for each exchange entry - number of files containing a value, or top or bottom N values, etc.

Comment: I will try implementing this soon, but it looks like exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your files are small, you could do something basic like this

```
data = dict()
for fname in os.listdir(csvDir):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as fin:
        data[fname] = dict((key, value) for key, value in fin.readlines())
# All the data is now loaded into your data dictionary
# data -> {'file1.csv': {1201007: 0.006, 1201032: 0.0119, 1201040: 0.0106}, 'file2.csv': ...}
```

Now everything is readily accessible for you to compare keys and their resultant values in your data dictionary.

Otherwise, if you have much larger datasets to work with that might not be loadable in memory you might want to consider just working with 2 files at a time, with one being stored in memory.  You can create a list of filename combinations with [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) which is you called like `combinations(filenames, 2)` would yield you a 2 filename pair out of unique combinations you can use.

From there you can still optimize further but that should get you going.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably sort the files before comparing them.  Then use an algorithm similar to the merge step of mergesort to do the comparisons.

You still need to think about what to do with duplicate records - EG, what if file1 has 1234567,0.1 twice, and so does file2?  And what if file1 has 3 of them, and file2 has 5 - and vice-versa?

```
http://en.literateprograms.org/Merge_sort_%28Python%29
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/sort-comparison/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort
```

Comment: They are already presorted. As for duplicates, there are absolutely no duplicates in a single file due to the type of data it is.